# Check if json has fields other than valid keys in struct

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and this could be so basic. Below is an example demonstrating my need. Junk should accept only id and name. Even though unmarshal eliminates extras, i need a way to hard stop execution stating json contain invalid key value pair. Could you please let me know if there's any.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Junk struct{
  ID int `json:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Area string `json:"area"`

}
func main() {
    a:=Junk{}
    data:= `{"id":1,"name":"gg","junk":"Junk value"}`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data),&a)
    if err!=nil{
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
        fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: What is different in Go to other languages: The official documentation is usable and it is _always_ worth reading the _whole_ package doc and at least to peek at all types and methods.

Comment: I totally agree with you that godoc has everything. I went through the method DisallowUnknownFields but it took decoder as argument. Description matched my need but wasn't sure of usage and confused if that is. Hence posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`func (*Decoder) DisallowUnknownFields()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields):

> DisallowUnknownFields causes the Decoder to return an error when the
> destination is a struct and the input contains object keys which do
> not match any non-ignored, exported fields in the destination.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Junk struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Area string `json:"area"`
}

func main() {
    a := Junk{}
    data := `{"id":1,"name":"gg","junk":"Junk value"}`

    d := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))
    d.DisallowUnknownFields()

    if err := d.Decode(&a); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Try it out: https://play.golang.org/p/aTj2C-AAuZ7

Comment: Just a note: `d.Decode` only tries to decode the first json object (and `json.Decoder` would expect more json object in the stream), so it won't check if there is invalid contents after the first json object. See: how https://play.golang.org/p/ntLUL5xspPg runs without error. Most of time this should not be a problem though.

Comment: @leafbebop thanks for pointing that out. Do you know if, in case someone wanted to throw an error in such a scenario, it would be enough to invoke [`More`](https://play.golang.org/p/db-7oH_M_kL)? or are there some other caveats one needs to consider?

Comment: @mkopriva More is error prone: https://play.golang.org/p/-Krqv1zFkWM. I think [this comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36225#issuecomment-567776561) and the issue it is in should cover most if not all cases.